# Show values in a table for the same item in reacts

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, datatables

I'm developing an application in React.JS

I have the array:

```
const array = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "202001"
      },
      "item": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "I1",
        "description": "item1"
      },
      "type": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "type1"
      },
      "price": 100,
      "unit": "unit1"
      },
      {
      "id": 2,
      "date": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "202002"
      },
      "item": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "I1",
        "description": "item1"
      },
      "type": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "type1"
      },
      "price": 200,
      "unit": "unit1"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "date": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "202002"
      },
      "item": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "I2",
        "description": "item2"
      },
      "type": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "type2"
      },
      "price": 300,
      "unit": "unit2"
    },
  ]
```

And I show the data as shown in the table:

| ITEM | TYPE | 202001 | 202002 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 // item1 | type1 | 100 // unit1 | 200 // unit1 | 300 |
| i2 // item2 | type1 | - | 300 // unit2 | 300 |
| TOTAL |  | 100 | 500 | 600 |

I did this to get some values:

```
items = array.reduce((acc, e) => {
    if (!acc[e["item"]["name"]]) {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]] = {
        [e["date"]["name"]]: e["price"],
        'type': e.type?.name,
        'description': e.item?.description,
      }
    } else {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]][e["date"]["name"]] = e["price"]
    }
    return acc
  }, {})

dates = [...new Set(Object.keys(items).map(i => Object.keys(items[i])).flat())]

totalSumPerDate = {};

dates.forEach(date => {
  const sumOnDate = Object.values(items).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc = acc + (curr[date]? curr[date] : 0);
    return acc;
  }, 0);
  totalSumPerDate[[date]] = sumOnDate;
});

totalSum = Object.values(totalSumPerDate).reduce((acc, curr) => acc+curr, 0);

sumPerItem = {};

Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
   const sum = Object.values(items[key]).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
   sumPerItem[[key]] = sum;
});
```

And to show the table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      {dates.map(date => <th>{date}</th>)}
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {
    Object.keys(items_dicc).map((item) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{item} // {items[item]?.description}</td>
          <td>{items[item]?.type}</td>
          {dates.map((date) => <td>{items[item][date] || ''}</td>)}
          <td>{sumPerItem[item]}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
  }
    <tr>
      <td>TOTAL</td>
        {Object.values(totalSumPerDate).map(item => <td>{item}</td>)}
      <td>{totalSum}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to add the `description`, `type` and `unit`, I tried to do it but it brings me everything in `dates`.

How can I fix it using the above to display the table correctly, suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you get rid of reduce() because it's just making a mess. All you need is a single map().

Comment: Hello @pguardiario! Thanks for your comment. I think the reduce makes things more complex, how can I do what you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For example:

{array.map(row => <tr>
  <td>{row.id}</td>
  <td>{row.date.id}</td>
  <td>{row.date.name}</td>
</tr>)}
```

Comment: Yes, this works but it doesn't group the items, which is what I'm trying to do. that you show all dates for the same item. how to do it inside this map? thanks!

Comment: I don't see you grouping items, I see you displaying 2 items.

Comment: shows two items, but for item1 there are two grouped items, for 202001 and 202002: id  1 and id 2

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. Maybe [this](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) is what you want.